# почему при добавление в ссылку символа, то компонента пропадает

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, route

```
            <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="page">
                <Routes>
                    <Route  path = "/profile" element = {<PageBody />}/>
                    <Route  path = "/messages/" element = {<Dialogs />}/>
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Допустим я зайду на ссылку http://localhost:3000/profile/1, то почему-то компонента PageBody пропадает. Обычно такое происходит, если писать exact или end (в зависимости от версии). сейчас я использую "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2", возможно прошло какое-то обновление, чтобы указать, что путь не должен быть точным

Comment: если заменить /profile на /profile/ будет то же самое?

Comment: Да, у messages так стоит, но проблема не пропала. Очень странная проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Из-за 6 версии react-route изменился немного синтаксис. Чтобы компонента не прободала нужно ввести звездочку при ее отсутствии route принимает старый атрибут exact.

```
<Route  path = "/messages*" element = {<Dialogs />}/>
```